# How to fix Vercel Deploy Next jS without any error notification?

Tags: next.js, vercel

I've developed NextJS Project and already deployed to Vercel. Today when I updated my code and pushed to Github, and begin to deploy on Vercel, it shows me error. Build logs is attached in screenshot.

[image]

I've tried to delete node_modules, cleaning cache and all, but it didn't work.
The strange thing I'm not seeing any error and the reason for failing. In my local host, everything is working perfectly and no errors whatsoever, but Vercel is not giving me any error but just one notification:

> Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1

Can somebody let me know please what could be the reason of it? I can see there are some warnings but these warnings I suppose are not the main cause of this strange issue.

Comment: Can you replicate the issue when running `npm run build` locally?

Comment: When I run `build` locally I get a warning, when it's deployed it shows the same message as an error. How do I make my local build treat warnings as errors?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply. After spending 2-3 hours , I had intentionally put an error in my code, deleted one dependency from node_modules to see the build logs of Vercel. And removed a component from my code. So during deployment on Vercel of ERROR Code, it has shown me the errors indeed. And when I undo my changes and again started to deploy, that works like a charm. Not sure what was the reason still. Might be Vercel got some bugs at that period of time in my account. LOL

[image: Removed one of the dependency from package.json]

Then Deployed again to Vercel. Then it has shown me some error that makes sense.

Screenshot is attached.

[image: Errors shown in Vercel]

After fixing that error, it worked !

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Edited my answer and attached details.